# Jump to location in org-mode while properly unfolding headings

Tags: org-mode, evil, navigation

I'd like to find a way to jump to a location in an org-mode file while automatically unfolding only the heading at the location I'm jumping to and all its parent headings (but not any sibling headings).

For example, if I have this org-mode file:

```
* A
** AA
*** AAA
** AB
*** ABA
* B
** BA
*** BAA
** BB
*** BBA
* C
** CA
*** CAA
** CB
*** CBA
```

and I use `evil-set-marker` to mark the location at `BBA`, and then fold up all the headings, the file will now be displayed in org-mode as:

```
* A...
* B...
* C...
```

and if I now `evil-goto-mark` with the intention of going back to `BBA`, emacs will only place point on `B` without unfolding any of the headings, so the way the file is displayed remains unchanged.

Instead, I'd like emacs to unfold just `BBA` and all of its parent headings (but no sibling headings) like so:

```
* A...
* B
** BA...
** BB
*** BBA
* C...
```

and place point on the exact location I marked at `BBA`.

Comment: `C-c C-r` is `org-reveal` which shows the hierachy above with out siblings.  `C-u C-c C-r` includes siblings too.  More control is availably via `org-show-context`

Comment: Unfortunately, `org-reveal` does not seem to solve my issue, or at least I can't figure out how to apply it to my problem.  Please see my comments in reply to Heikki's answer below.

Comment: Your last display is exactly what `C-u C-c C-r` gives in this situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does absolutely nothing for me.  I've described the exact steps I tried in my replies to Heikki's answer below.  For a moment I suspect that maybe this was because I had an older version of evil installed, but I just installed the newest version from git and it still doesn't work.  (I'm using emacs 25.3.1 on Gentoo amd64)

Answer (score 1):

You could define a custom function :

```
(defun evil-goto-and-unfold ()
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (evil-goto-mark)
    (show-subtree)))
```

It is untested as-is as I do not use evil-mode myself, but might work as I bumped on the same limitations/weirdnesses of `org-reveal` as you, and I solved it with `show-subtree`.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want -- except it does not show the sister heading `BA`.

```
Function Signature
(org-reveal &optional SIBLINGS)

Documentation
Show current entry, hierarchy above it, and the following headline.

This can be used to show a consistent set of context around
locations exposed with org-show-context.

With optional argument SIBLINGS, on each level of the hierarchy all
siblings are shown.  This repairs the tree structure to what it would
look like when opened with hierarchical calls to org-cycle.

With a C-u C-u prefix, go to the parent and show the entire tree.

Key Bindings
org-mode-map <menu-bar> <Org> <Show/Hide> <Reveal Context>
org-mode-map C-c C-r
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting org-reveal to do anything when the headings are all folded and point is on `* B ...` (where `evil-goto-mark` places it).  Could you give an example of exactly how when I could use this command?

Comment: Put cursor on the BBA line in your sample text, press `Shift-Tab` until the mini-buffer says OVERVIEW. The press `C-c C-r` to reveal the cursor line and its parents.

Comment: I see what you mean, and that does work in the case when point is actually on the `BBA` line and `org-shift-tab` is used to fold up the outline.  But the situation I described in my question is quite different: I've not only folded up the outline but also moved point away from `BBA`.  I need to both jump back to the `BBA` line and then unfold properly.  I don't see how I can do that.  If I do an `evil-set-marker` at `BBA`, fold up the outline, move point away, and then `evil-goto-marker`, emacs takes me back to just the folded `* B...` line where `org-reveal` does nothing.

Comment: Try this: Put cursor on `BBA`, press `C-Space` (set-mark-command) twice and and move the cursor away. When you want to return, press `C-u C-Space` to return to the mark. You can then fold the org hierarchy the way you want using `Shift-tab` or `org-reveal`. The only caveat is that before you return, you might run a command that automatically sets the mark in a new position.

Comment: Thank you for staying with me for this.  Unfortunately, after I put my cursor on `BBA` and press `C-Space` twice and move the cursors away, `C-u C-Space` does *not* return to the mark for me.  If I had pressed `C-Space` only once instead of twice, then `C-u C-Space` does return to the mark for me.  But even then, returning to the mark only works if I haven't in the meantime folded up the outline.  I want to be able to first fold up the outline before returning to the mark, and have the outline automatically unfolded as I have described in my original question when I return to mark.

Comment: It is possible that your setup has remapped keys from standard layout so much that giving exact instructions is difficult. I do not use evil, so I can not help you there. You should debug the situation with emacs without any extra modules `emacs -Q` and see how things work there. Then you should explore what commands your key bindings run. Use `C-h k` for that. Also, try running command using the name, with `M-x`.

Comment: I tried this with `emacs -Q`:  1 - Completely unfolded the outline that starts with the `B` line.  2 - Moved point to `BBA`.  3 - Pressed `C-Space` twice.  4 - Moved point to the `B` line and folded the entire outline.  5 - Moved point to `A`.  6 - Pressed `C-u C-Space`, which took me to the left-most period on the `* B...` line (the outline is still completely folded at this point).  7 - Typed `M-x org-reveal` and nothing happened (other than a message appearing saying "You can run org-reveal with C-r C-r" -- so org-reveal did run).

Comment: The crucial thing is that there are commands in emacs that automatically sets the mark. You did not say how you moved the point. For example, if you used isearch it sets the mark to the starting position. Read the penultimate paragraph: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Isearch.html . if you move using arrow keys, mark is not set.

Comment: In my description above when I say I "moved point" I did it using `C-n` and `C-p`, which should not set the mark.

Answer (score -1):

Lisp function `org-show-context` works.
This is the command used by me to open file at point.

```
(defun my-find-file-at-point-with-line ()
  "Opens the file at point and goes to line-number."
  (interactive)
  ;; TODO: support file like "d:\\asbc\\dd.txt"
  (if (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
    (org-open-at-point)
    (let ((fname (ffap-file-at-point)))
      (if fname
        (let ((line
               (save-excursion
                 (goto-char (cadr ffap-string-at-point-region))
                 (and (re-search-backward ":\\([0-9]+\\)"
                                          (line-beginning-position) t)
                      (string-to-number (match-string 1))))))
          ;;(message "file:%s,line:%s" fname line)
          (when (and (tramp-tramp-file-p default-directory)
                     (= ?/ (aref fname 0)))
            ;; if fname is an absolute path in remote machine, it will not return a tramp path,fix it here.
            (let ((pos (position ?: default-directory)))
              (if (not pos) (error "failed find first tramp indentifier ':'"))
              (setf pos (position ?: default-directory :start (1+ pos)))
              (if (not pos) (error "failed find second tramp indentifier ':'"))
              (setf fname (concat (substring default-directory 0 (1+ pos)) fname))))
          (find-file-existing fname)
          (when line (goto-line line))
          ;; make sure context in point is visible.
          (when (and buffer-file-name (string-match "\\.org$" buffer-file-name))
            (org-show-context)))
        (warn "File does not exist.")))))
```

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Please expand your answer to show how OP can use this function.

Comment: What @Dan said. Define "works"; show how it works.